# arrange a graph with random edges

Tags: python, random, graph, networkx

I'm using python and networkx to randomly assign edges to nods.  the nods are in three categories (white, black and other) and each category has 33 nodes. the code is working but I have two questions:
1- How can I make sure one node will not selected twice? I mean lets say in the first round an edge was defined between node 4 and 56. how can i make sure in round 4 this edge wont be selected again?
2- For the next step that I want to do is to assign wight. It means for example if x is white then y is A% more likely to be white.  How can i add that to this?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy

G=nx.Graph()
w=1
b=34
o=67

while w < 34:
    G.add_node(w, race='white')
    w+=1
while b < 67:
    G.add_node(b, race='black')
    b+=1
while o < 100:
    G.add_node(o, race='other')
    o+=1


from numpy import random as rand
###first round edges assignment
num1edge = int(raw_input("Please enter number of edges you want to start with: "))
i=0
while i< num1edge:
    x1 = rand.randint (1, 99)
    y1 = rand.randint (x1, 99)
    G.add_edge(x1,y1)
    i+=1

numrounds = int(raw_input("Please enter how many times you want to run: "))
numedge = int(raw_input("Please enter number of edges you want to be created in each round: "))                      
j = 0
k = 0
while j < numrounds:
    while k  < num1edge:
        x = rand.randint (1, 99)
        y = rand.randint (x, 99)
        G.add_edge(x,y)
        k+=1
    j+=1
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an adjacency matrix. The interception between rows and columns give you the relation between nods. For instance, lets say you have only 3 nodes. 1, 2 and 3, so if you have the next matrix

```
     1   2   3
     _________
1 |  0   0   0
2 |  0   0   1
3 |  0   0   0
```

that means that edge between nodes 2 and 3 has been selected. If you select another, lets say (1,2), just update your matrix:

```
your_matrix[1][2] = 1
```